# Video conferencing that deals well with multiple simultaneous speakers?

Tags: video-conferencing

Every year my family and I have a big group call with 10-20 participants. We used Google Meet this year, and everyone had a lot of audio problems when more than one person tried to talk at once (I've observed the same issue when using Google Meet at work). That's fine for a business environment where there's often just one presenter, but for a big group of people trying to have a spontaneous conversation it's not good.

We've used Skype before, which worked ok -- we only tried Meet because of the no-download-required feature.

What's the best video conferencing software for *conversations* among a big-ish group of people, instead of presentations?

Answer (score 0):

You might appreciate [tawk.space](https://github.com/invisible-college/tawk.space) - with demo instance at https://tawk.space/ - which describes itself as a cafe like space where you hear those closer to you.